# Can i install a water pump to an overhead tank having a single piping system?

Tags: plumbing

[image]i have an overhead tank on my roof where it is filled and drained by single pipe system. but the pressure is too low at the different outlets (kitchen, bathroom, toilet). i want to connect a pump in this system. is it feasible?

Comment: could you add more pictures and a more detailed explanation of the piping and tank?

Answer (score 1):

Is the tank a pressure tank or a non-pressure tank? If it is a pressure tank, you could move the tank from the roof to the supply line just after a newly installed  pump. Add a pressure switch and a Domestic PRV. Location of the parts would be as follows:  1) supply line; 2) domestic water pump; 3) pressure gauge; 4) pressure shut off switch; 5) pressure tank; 6) domestic PRV; 7) domestic water line. The pressure switch would be set at approximately 50/60 PSIG. to cycle the pump and the PRV could be set at 40/50 PSIG.  Note; this is the same set up as a well system. The PRV could be eliminated if you desire. Also the pump should be for domestic use (bronze or stainless steel). If the tank is a non-pressure tank, adding a pump would be difficult. I hope this helps. If the tank is a non-pressurized type, you could , if you had a separate fill line, add a pump, small expansion tank,  and pressure switch to the delivery line, set the pressure switch for the desired line pressure. The pump would maintain a constant pressure on the supply line of say 40 to 60 PSIG or whatever pressure you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure out the system here.. it appears that the system is filled from street level, with that ball valve closed, and that when water starts spurting out the top of that open pipe the tank is full. If that is the case, the check valve, pump, and pressure tank should be installed between the two vertical pipes.